# how to extract github issues programmatically

Tags: github-api

I know you can extract git logs by cloning the repository and running this command `git log --pretty=format:"%H ,%an ,%ae ,%ad ,%cn ,%ce ,%cd ,%s"  >OpenCV.csv` but how can you extract git issues and the information inside it like the message of issue comment. [image]

Comment: Did you even open the API docs? https://developer.github.com/v3/issues or the GraphQL API https://developer.github.com/v4/

Comment: I did open the API docs. No I did not open GraphQL API. Is there any faster way to get it like the same way to get the git logs?

Comment: `git` has no issues. `github`, a website providing a `git` server, provides issues. Therefore you cannot use `git` to list issues. You need an API to access the web site. That's not really more difficult than calling a `git` command though.

Comment: Yes, as seen on my screenshot. I want to get the issues of a certain repositories in github. If it needs an API to get the issue, can you point me to a link that has a procedure to start with. Thanks.

Comment: The link above with the REST API documentation.